# How to properly handle a Docker container as a systemd service?

Tags: debian, docker, systemd, debian-stretch

I handle many services (databases, web servers...) implemented by docker containers via systemd units.
It works, but the system takes a very long time to shut down, apparently waiting for docker services to shut down.

Here is an example of a systemd unit I made in a virtual machine under Debian Stretch with Docker CE :

**/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=MariaDB
After=docker.service
Requires=docker.service

[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=0
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --rm \
    --name=mariadb \
    -p 3306:3306 \
    -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root \
    -e MYSQL_DATABASE=test \
    -e MYSQL_USER=user \
    -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=user \
    -v /var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql \
    mariadb:latest
ExecStop=-/usr/bin/docker stop mariadb # See UPDATEs 1 & 2

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The service starts and stops properly in seconds when I use systemctl command. But when I shut the system down, it shows :

[image: VM screenshot 1]
[image: VM screenshot 2]
[image: VM screenshot 3]

It lasts more than 3 minutes. It can be longer if there are many containers running via systemd.

The problem is not specific to MariaDB.

Is there a better method to handle docker containers via systemd, avoiding extra shutdown time ?

- UPDATE 1 : As Bennett Hardwick suggested in comment, I tried removing the ExecStop directive from the definition of the service. It seems better since the service stops after 1min 30 and not 3min.
- UPDATE 2 : I tried to add the option -t to docker stop command in ExecStop directive (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/). It has no effect.

Comment: Does leaving ExecStop blank speed it up at all? I imagine the docker service already handles stopping running containers.

Comment: Yes it seems to wait only 1min30 instead of 3min to stop the container.

Comment: Please add to the post the Dockerfile.

Comment: @harrymc I have no specific Dockerfile to post because 1) my example is based on a docker image which is available via Docker Hub 2) as I mentioned in my question, the problem is not specific to this image. I think you can reproduce it with any container.

Comment: Have you looked at [systemd-docker](https://github.com/ibuildthecloud/systemd-docker)?

Comment: Yes I used it a while ago, until it did not work with the latest Docker releases. It seems to be no longer maintained since 2015.

Comment: Apparently systemd-docker can still be made to work. See [this post](https://github.com/ibuildthecloud/systemd-docker/issues/50) and especially the last entry about building a forked version from scratch. Try it before I post it as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

A solution which is no longer maintained is
[systemd-docker](https://github.com/ibuildthecloud/systemd-docker),
described as:

> This is a wrapper for docker run so that you can sanely run Docker
>   containers under systemd. The key thing that this wrapper does is move
>   the container process from the cgroups setup by Docker to the service
>   unit's cgroup. This handles a bunch of other quirks so please read
>   through documentation to get an understanding of all the implications
>   of running Docker under systemd.
>
> Using this wrapper you can manage containers through systemctl or the
>   docker CLI and everything should just stay in sync. Additionally you
>   can leverage all the cgroup functionality of systemd and
>   systemd-notify.

The problem of getting systemd-docker to work with recent Linux versions is
discussed in the post
[Doesn't work with recent systemd and/or docker releases](https://github.com/ibuildthecloud/systemd-docker/issues/50) ,
where a user named james-cxx has reported success:

> I was able to get systemd-docker working with Ubuntu 18.04 by:
>
> - Building systemd-docker from scratch from [@agend07 's fork](https://github.com/agend07), per @agend07 and @Halfwalker
>     discussed above.
> - Adding `--cgroups name=systemd` just after `systemd-docker` in the unit file, per
>     https://container-solutions.com/running-docker-containers-with-systemd/
>
> My *guess* is that docker defaults to not using systemd for cgroups
>   because "the delegate issues still exists and systemd currently does
>   not support the cgroup feature set required for containers run by
>   docker" (per the docker.service unit file), and I expect
>   systemd-docker is expecting systemd for the cgroups, hence the `open
>   /sys/fs/cgroup/system.slice/docker.service/cgroup.procs: no such file
>   or directory` error. Setting `--cgroups name=systemd` apparently
>   overrides the docker default, however, I cannot say what side-effects
>   this may have, given the ominous note in the docker.service unit file.

An alternative to systemd-docker might be to use
[rkt](https://coreos.com/rkt/), described as:

> rkt is an application container engine developed for modern production
>   cloud-native environments. It features a pod-native approach, a
>   pluggable execution environment, and a well-defined surface area that
>   makes it ideal for integration with other systems.

Comment: A more up to date clone of systemd-docker is available at https://github.com/DonTseTse/systemd-docker, and a build container is available at https://github.com/DonTseTse/systemd-docker_build-container.